# How to validate all text or send the data by submit image in html button tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have used the submit image between the button tag to send the data on my mail id but when i clicked on button it redirect to next page without filled the data into text boxes and not getting the mail on my mail id. php script also used for this. i have checked many times but not get success so please help me out how to validate & send the data on mail. ican't under stand where is issue  :

```
enter code here
<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "sandeepdoliya110@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
      $city = $_POST['city'];
       $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
         $email = $_POST['email'];
          $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";

     $message = $first_name . "\n " . $last_name . " \n" .$address1. "\n " .$address2 . "\n " . $state . "\n " . $city . "\n " .  $pincode . " \n" . $phone . "\n " . $email . "\n " . $payment_type ."\n\n" ;
    $message2 = "Thank you for showing interest. We will Contact You Soon " . $first_name . "\n " . $last_name . " \n" .$address1. "\n " .$address2 . "\n " . $state . "\n " . $city . "\n " .  $pincode . " \n" . $phone . "\n " . $email . "\n " . $payment_type ."\n\n" ;

     $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    @mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    @mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.


}

else{
    echo "something is wrong";
}

?>

html part is :

 <!-- Form -->
                    <form name="package-payment" id="package-payment" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group" id="error-message">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label" required>First Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required name="first_name" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" required name="last_name" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address 1</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1" required name="address1" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address 2</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="address2" name="address2"required name="address2" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <select id="state" name="state" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="State" option=""></option>
                                            <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                                            <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                            <option value="Arunachal Pradesh">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                                            <option value="Assam">Assam</option>
                                            <option value="Bihar">Bihar</option>
                                            <option value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                                            <option value="Chhattisgarh">Chhattisgarh</option>
                                            <option value="Dadra and Nagar Haveli">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                                            <option value="Daman and Diu">Daman and Diu</option>
                                            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                                            <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                                            <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                                            <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                                            <option value="Himachal Pradesh">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                                            <option value="Jammu and Kashmir">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                                            <option value="Jharkhand">Jharkhand</option>
                                            <option value="Karnataka">Karnataka</option>
                                            <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
                                            <option value="Lakshadweep">Lakshadweep</option>
                                            <option value="Madhya Pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                                            <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                                            <option value="Manipur">Manipur</option>
                                            <option value="Meghalaya">Meghalaya</option>
                                            <option value="Mizoram">Mizoram</option>
                                            <option value="Nagaland">Nagaland</option>
                                            <option value="Orissa">Orissa</option>
                                            <option value="Pondicherry">Pondicherry</option>
                                            <option value="Punjab">Punjab</option>
                                            <option value="Rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
                                            <option value="Sikkim">Sikkim</option>
                                            <option value="Tamil Nadu">Tamil Nadu</option>
                                            <option value="Tripura">Tripura</option>
                                            <option value="Uttaranchal">Uttaranchal</option>
                                            <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                                            <option value="West Bengal">West Bengal</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city" required name="city" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pincode</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="pincode" name="pincode" required name="pincode" maxlength="6" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required name="phone" maxlength="12" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="email"  name="email" value="" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Shipping</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <p class=" custom_form_fields_reeadonly"><b class="black-text"><i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>. 199/-</b></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Amount</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <p class=" custom_form_fields_reeadonly">MRP. <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>. <s>2,600/-</s> &nbsp; <b class="orange-text font-bolder">Offer <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>. 1,299/-</b></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Payment</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9 padd-top-05em">
                                        <input value="cod" name="payment_type" id="cod" checked="checked" type="radio"><b class="padd-right-1em"> Cash on Delivery</b>  
                                        <input value="prepaid" name="payment_type" id="prepaid"  type="radio"><b> Prepaid</b> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="clearfix"></div>
                 <!--       <input name="gateway" type="hidden" id="gateway" />                         
                        <input type="hidden" name="ch" id="ch" value="" />                          
                        <input type="hidden" name="ssd" id="ssd" value=""/>                         
                        <input type="hidden" name="ocode" id="ocode" value=""/>                         
                        <input type="hidden" value="2922" id="page_id" name="page_id"/>                         
                        <input type="hidden" value="1498" id="amount" name="amount"/>                           
                        <input type="hidden" value="1498" id="payu_amount" name="payu_amount"/>                         
                        <input type="hidden" value="25" id="product_id" name="product_id"/>                         
                        <input type="hidden" value="fitband" id="product_info" name="product_info"/>-->
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <button type="button"  onclick="location.href = 'contact.php';" name="submit" value="submit" class="submitbtn">
                                <img src="images/button-buy-now.png"  alt="submit" style="padding:18px 0px; width:190px;">

                            </button>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span class="brand-color"><b>Mail Us:</b></span><i class="font-bolder">support@neutrikart.com</i>&nbsp; 
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!-- Icons -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 icon-form-box black-text text-uppercase text-shadow-black">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 padd-top-1em">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="icon-number font-bolder">100%</td>
                                <td>risk-free purchase</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 icon-number-top  padd-top-1em">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="icon-number font-bolder">COD</td>
                                <td>cash-on delivery</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 icon-number-top  padd-top-1em">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="icon-number font-bolder">48-Hrs</td>
                                <td>money-back guarantee</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 icon-number-top  padd-top-1em animated fadeInDown">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td class="icon-number font-bolder">50%</td>
                                <td>Discounted Price</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The redirect happens because you explicitely are doing so: `<button type="button"  onclick="location.href = 'contact.php';" name="submit" value="submit" class="submitbtn">`" Remove the `onclick` attribute and use a button type of submit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are submitting to same page, remove the

```
action=""
```

on your form.

Change submit button type from
     type="button" 
To
    type="submit"